# How can I stack columns vertically when viewport width changes in bootstrap 4?

Tags: web, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I have a webpage for desktop like the one [image: Desktop webpage]

When user views this page on mobile, I would like the columns to be rearranged like below:[image: Mobile webpage]

I am unable to figure out how to rearrange the labels so that they move next to the drown downs, and the search text box moved to the next row.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Please share the code you've attempted so far and explain what's not working

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Grid system of `Bootstrap4` to arrange the rows and columns elements

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

You can also check it out here as well

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Then you would also need to reordering the columns over the small devices.Here are couple of references that may help you.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#reordering

Here is a working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<style>
  @media(min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px){
      .col-sm-6{
    width: 50% !important;
  }
  .drop.order-sm-2.order-md-1.order-1 {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    order: 2;
}
.label.order-sm-1.order-md-2.order-2 {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    order: 1;
  }
  }
@media (min-width:640px){
  .order-sm-2 {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    order: 2;
}
  .order-sm-3 {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    order: 2;
}
/*.drop.order-sm-2.order-md-1.order-1 {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    order: 2;
}
.label.order-sm-1.order-md-2.order-2 {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    order: 1;
  }*/
}
 @media(min-width: 580px) and (max-width: 768px){
  .order-3 {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 4;
    -ms-flex-order: 3;
    order: 3;
}
.drop.order-sm-2.order-md-1.order-1 {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    order: 2;
}
.label.order-sm-1.order-md-2.order-2 {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    order: 1;
  }
}

</style>
<body>

<div class="container">

 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 order-sm-2 order-md-1 order-1 drop">
          <select class="form-control"> 
              <option>select dropdown 1</option>
            </select>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 order-sm-1 order-md-2 order-2 label">
        drop 1
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 order-md-3 order-3 order-sm-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search box">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Search">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 order-md-2  order-ms-2 order-lg-3 order-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 order-sm-2 order-md-1 order-1 drop">
          <select class="form-control"> 
              <option>select dropdown 2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 order-sm-1 order-md-2 order-2 label">
         drop 2
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope the above references would be more helpful.